# SQL - Conditional Joins based on Results in Query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, conditional-statements

```
Select a.OPID, b.Name, b.Dept
from table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
where
(CASE 
WHEN a.OPID like 'D%'
THEN a.OPID = c.OPID and c.OPID = b.ID
ELSE a.OPID = b.ID
END);
```

Table1 contains two types of accounts, numeric accounts and sub-accounts starting with the letter D. The sub-accounts are tied to a numeric account on table3, but I need to get the personal data off table 2 which only has numeric accounts.

I need a different set of joins on records beginning with D than on numeric records. I want to avoid using unions if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Your joins don't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this `JOIN` logic:

```
Select a.OPID, b.Name, b.Dept
from table1 a left join
     table3 c
     on a.OPID = c.OPID and a.OPID like 'D%' left join
     table2 b
     on (b.ID = c.OPID and a.OPID like 'D%') or
        (b.ID = a.OPID and a.OPID not like 'D%');
```

Perhaps you have oversimplified the problem.  But the logic `a.OPID = c.OPID and c.OPID = b.ID` is the same as `a.OPID = b.ID`, so your logic is still:

```
Select a.OPID, b.Name, b.Dept
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on b.ID = a.OPID;
```

Perhaps you oversimplified the problem, but if not, this might actually be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hows this?

```
select  a.OPID, b.Name, b.Dept from table1 a join table2 b
    on a.OPID = b.ID
    Where a.OPID like 'D%'
    union 
    select  a.OPID, b.Name, b.Dept from table1 a join table3 b
    on a.OPID = b.ID
    WHEre a.OPID not like 'D%'
```